# How to stop update for Mencoder & mplayer in my system (14.04)?

Tags: mplayer, mencoder

I have 14.04 installed but I have problem with **mencoder** & **mplayer** which always want to update to version from 2012
But I compiled **mencoder** & **mplayer** from sources so I get newest version.

How exclude **mencoder** & **mplayer** from updating ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system wants to update **Mencoder** and **Mplayer**, this is because you have installed them using the packages provided by the Ubuntu software repositories.

If you prefer to use the most recent version that you compile yourself from the sources, then you should remove the version provided by Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get purge mencoder mplayer
```

After doing so, your system will stop managing the update to these software, you will just need to compile from sources yourself each time you need a new recent version.

### Updated

As the OP tells in the comment, he is using the guide provided in the [Help Cener of Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Compiling%20MPlayer).
I've reviewed this guide and found out that, yes, this will allow to build the **mencoder** & **mplayer** from source but the process described there will also create .deb package out of them and install them as any other Ubuntu package.

As seen in the procedure : to compile **MPlayer** you are asked to add the following parameter to an install command : `--pkgversion "2:1.0~svn$(LC_ALL=C svn info 2> /dev/null | grep Revision | cut -d' ' -f2)"` therefore fixing a version into this package which is **inferior to the one found for this package in the repositories**.

Thus it is now understandable why after following the tutorial, the software are updated along with any `apt-get upgrade`.

So, or you manually provide an higher value to the version string, or you follow the post referred by the [duplicate note](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) in your question to lock the package and avoid they are updated with the system.

Comment: as i write i dont install it from repos but from sources but it still wants update them

Comment: Could you details in your question the commands / operations / manipulation you do to "compile from source". Are you using the upstream source package or a Debian source package ? Because when compiling from source using the upstream package, there won't be any automatic update when you do ``sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Compiling%20MPlayer i use this manual to compile